# What is the best way to reference a core data entity?

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-data

I have been reading and working a lot with core data recently, and I love the way it implements the data storage.

However, there is one thing I am still not able to resolve in my app.

On my data model, I have an entity which represents a chunk of text the user have inserted in a text field. I want to be able to give the user the possibility to embed this chuck of text into another text field by referencing it.

If I was working with a database directly, I would do something like this:

1. The user adds a chunk of text to the database. It happens to have the row index `17`.
2. The user goes back to the main editor where it can reference chunks of text from the database and inserts a pattern such as `{chunk.17}` where `17` is the row index in the database.
3. The user clicks a "parse" button, making the app query the database for this row and replace the string `{chunk.17}` for the text chunk stored in there.

Since Core Data has no such thing as an auto incremented index, I am not sure how to create a similar behavior without much work. Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: As an aside... a note in response to your comment... "Core Data has no such thing as an auto incremented index". If you are using `NSSQLiteStoreType`, and you are persisting data without the use of `NSManagedDocument`, you can (via Terminal) open the SQLite db and inspect the database. You will note that when Core Data creates each table it also creates `Z_PK INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, which is an auto-incremental primary key. I understand that this is not directly accessible in code, but it exists. Not related to your question, I know, just wanted to provide this information as background.

Comment: In response to your question, are you preparing an `NSManagedObject` subclass for each of the entities in your data model that you would like to access in your code?

Comment: @andrewbuilder Yes. I am using the classes generated by Xcode as they are and using categories to build over them.

Comment: Are you using UITableViewController class and view to manage and present your data? That is, how are you presenting this to your user?

Comment: I'm sorry but this is on OS X. I am using a document based app with a `NSPersistentDocument`. To display data I am using a simple `NSFetchRequest`.

Comment: OK sorry I'm only familiar with Core Data on iOS. Did JShapiro's answer help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you'll need to add a property (such as "id") to your entity that has some unique value (there are lots of discussions on Stackoverflow about how to generate a unique ID/value for an object).  Once you have that, you can reference this value using an NSPredicate:

```
NSFetchRequest *req = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Demo"];
// A predicate is used as a limited substitute for a 'where' clause.  In this case, we're specifying that
// the result set should only contain entities whose id is 'chunk.17'.
[req setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K LIKE[c] %@", @"id", @"chunk.17"]];

NSError *error;
NSArray *results = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:req error:&error];
```

Comment: Why not allow the user to specify the 'identity', particularly if they are going to be entering it again later before triggering a 'parse'... Also, be careful with `LIKE[c]` as it allows wildcards and user entered content could result in issues...

Comment: Agreed - if you are going to let the user set the identity, LIKE[c] should be used with caution.  My suggestion above was based on the premise that the identity would be set programmatically.